# Login pages don't work inside iFrame in CRM 4.0

Tags: iframe, authentication, dynamics-crm-4

So I have a Entity form with an iFrame in one of the tabs. There is a login page link in the URL of the iFrame with the username provided in the URL; somewhat like http://www.mywebsitepage/login?username=blahblah. When I open up the form, the login page is shown in the iFrame with the username already keyed in. I type in the password and hit Enter and the same login page is returned. It doesn't seem to go to the successful login page; whereas it works fine from normal browser. I have tried checking the "Pass record object-type code and unique identifier as parameters" but it doesn't seem to work either.

Please assist. I am using CRM 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution to this is adding the website inside the iFrame to the "Trusted Sites" in Internet Explorer.